# Package/stack collisions in ROS Wiki index

Tags: ros, documentation, wiki

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I opted to use avr_bridge on one of the projects that I am working on, and choose to use it as a git submodule.

This essentially creates a second (sub) git repository nested inside of the first (main) repository.

A nasty side effect of this is that the wiki now believes that avr_bridge is part of my project.  If you visit the wiki page for [avr_bridge](http://www.ros.org/wiki/avr_bridge), you will notice that it seems to be part of the au_automow_drivers stack, which is obviously incorrect.

First, is there any way to fix this?  And second, what can I do to prevent this from happening again?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/9422/package/stack-collisions-in-ros-wiki-index/) by [mjcarroll](https://answers.ros.org/users/9/mjcarroll/) on ROS Answers with karma: 6414 on 2011-03-15

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The indexer has to do "first one wins" as it's not possible to determine which is the authoritative source of a package.  One of the reasons we encourage external stack releases now is to more cleanly separate contributed software from development trees.

To deal with this, I have moved automow down in the index.

---

Originally posted by [kwc](https://answers.ros.org/users/11/kwc/) with karma: 12244 on 2011-03-15

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [mjcarroll](https://answers.ros.org/users/9/mjcarroll/) on 2011-03-16**:
Does this hold true with "stackless" packages?  avr_bridge exists outside of a stack, so I'm not entirely sure how to fit it into my ROS setup.

**Comment by [mjcarroll](https://answers.ros.org/users/9/mjcarroll/) on 2011-03-15**:
I'll update my repositories to reflect that suggestion, thanks.

**Comment by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) on 2011-03-15**:
As convenient as submodule is, like svn externals it only works with the same VCS.  We recommend using rosinstall and setting up a standard rosinstall file to use for your project.  This will allow you to pull in any repo conveniently, without affecting others who want to checkout your versioned code.